# ? operator to avoid NoSuchMethodError in dart

Tags: dart, nosuchmethoderror

I saw a video of someone try to avoid NoSuchMethodError by using ? operator . here's the code:

```
/*1*/ void main () {

/*2*/ var v = vu() ;
/*3*/ var f = v.casting()  ;
/*4*/ f.tbu ;

/*5*/}
```

**show error on line 4**

> Unhandled exception: NoSuchMethodError: The
> getter 'tbu' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: tbu

**but he used the ? operator :**

```
/*1*/ void main () {

/*2*/ var v = vu() ;
/*3*/ var f = v.casting()  ;
/*4*/ f?.tbu ;

/*5*/}
```

run without problem .

> My question is what is the ? operator ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mark placed before the dot allows [conditional property access](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#conditional-property-access), which guards against trying to access a property or method of an object that might be null:

```
myObject?.someProperty
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
(myObject != null) ? myObject.someProperty : null
```

This is similar to [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in JavaScript.